# Laravel Nova Date field always submits null

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

A Date field in one of my Nova resources always submits null, even when a date value has been selected from the picker. DateTime works fine. Snippets from pertinent code below:

MIGRATION

```
$table->date('shipment_date');
```

MODEL

```
protected $fillable = [
    'shipment_date',
    *... other fields*
];

protected $casts = [
    'shipment_date' => 'date',
];
```

RESOURCE

```
Date::make('Shipment Date', 'shipment_date')
    ->rules([
        'required',
    ])
```

Upon submitting the form, the field is highlight with red error text: "The Shipment Date field is required". It returns http status 422.

Viewing the request payload in Telescope:

```
{
"shipment_date": null,
*... other fields*
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in Nova and was fixed by the developers in version 3.9.3 released Sept 14 2020. See details here: https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/2853